# Eclipse "Toggle Comment" Shortcut Indents on New Projects

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Today I noticed that now when I Ctrl+/ one or more lines in Eclipse (.java files) it does comment them with //, but now moves the text over. However, testing this with older projects currently in the workspace, it acts as before - the line remains at the same indentation. For instance:

**What I want:**

```
    public Test()
    {
        _handler = new Handler();
    }
```

Becomes

```
    public Test()
    {
//      _handler = new Handler();
    }
```

**What happens:**

```
    public Test()
    {
        _handler = new Handler();
    }
```

Becomes

```
    public Test()
    {
//        _handler = new Handler();
    }
```

I tried making a new Java project, and a new Android project (the two I use), and both had the problem. They do not have project-specific settings enabled. I also use a custom Formatter profile, but using any of the three built-in ones did the same thing.

Does anyone know how to fix this so it keeps the line at the same indentation?

Thanks,
Amy

**Extra Info:**
Eclipse version Indigo, build id 20110916-0149
Android SDK R15 installed

Comment: are you sure the issue is with the version of Eclipse and not the settings or the code on the 2 different projects?  If you have tabs in one project and spaces in the other, then tabbed version may absorb the extra 2 characters of indentation, but with all-spaces it would not absorb the extra characters.

Comment: Well I just pasted the old-working-code into a new project file, and yes you're right. I didn't realize it was using spaces instead of tabs for indentations. Whelp I feel dumb, but thanks for the answer. If you reply in the official answer box I'd be happy to accept it, not sure what proper etiquette is.

Comment: Not to be petty, but could you please upvote my answer too, to get the max reputation out of it?  It's fairly standard to *both* upvote and select an answer.

Comment: Oh, of course. I honestly didn't notice there were upvote buttons on the comments too, I'd be happy to.

Comment: Thanks, but actually I meant my Answer, not my comment.  There are no reputation bestowed for upvoted comment -- that's just more or less an attention getter.  There are, however, 15 rep point for the selected answer (thank you, and glad it helped you), and _another_ 10 rep points awarded to the answerer for every user (including yourself) who also up-vote the answer by clicking on the little up-arrow above the big number next to each answer.

Comment: D'oh, I'm a dummy who can't read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem could be tabs versus spaces in the two projects.  Tabs may absorb the extra characters for commenting, whereas all-spaces for indenting does not absorb the comment characters.